# attempting to add data to list using landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, dataextensions, landing-page

I have created a landing page and I am trying to add the details to the list. But I am unable to do so. The landing page contains the fields like email address, first name etc. When I enter the details in the landing page its shows message, the update successfully. But when i check in the list, the data entered is not found. Can you please help me to solve this problem???

Thanks,
Smita

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange.  Please post some code and we'll have a look.